# Change a directive template using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a few buttons with `ng-click` in a controller and I want to change the a directive template when I click on a button. What is the best way to achieve this? (I will later use a slide in effect of the element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directive:

```
myModule.directive('foo', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            templateType: '@'
        },
        template: '<div ng-if="templateType == \'a\'">' +
            '    this is template A ' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div ng-if="templateType == \'b\'">' +
            '    this is template B ' +
            '</div>'
    };
});
```

Template:

```
<foo template-type="{{ templateType }}"></foo>
<a ng-click="templateType = 'b'" href="">Set template to b</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.templateType = 'a';
```

Comment: I would suggest to use different routes/view for each partial-view

Comment: what if both the templates are big..?

Comment: Then you would externalize the template to a file and use templateUrl, as for any other directive.

Comment: @JBNizet then how does you pass `templateType` value to templateUrl

Comment: You don't pass the templateType to the templateUrl. You pass it to the directive, the same way as above. Embedding the template in the directive or loading it from a URL doesn't change the way a directive works.

Comment: @JBNizet that is what I'm asking how would you pass `templateType ` value to `templateUrl` function

Comment: templateUrl is not a function. It's a string, containing the URL of the template on the server. So instead of writing `template: 'html code'`, you write `templateUrl: 'url of the html file containing the html code'`. The rest is identical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77390/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the example provided by @JB Nizet and use `ng-include` to swap templates, and managing larger size templates becomes easier.

```
myModule.directive('foo', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            templateType: '@'
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="\'/templateRoot/\' + templateType">'+
                  '</div>'
    };
});
```

Now you can create separate template files and make them available on specific url (in this case `/templateroot/a` or `/templateroot/b`)

Comment: using `ng-include` does make sense..+1